# How to get Powershell sort LastWriteTime to recognize AM vs PM?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am using `$file = dir *.txt | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1` to try and get the most recent text file in a folder, this works as long as all of the files were modified either before or after 1pm. If there is a mix instead of grabbing a file created at 1:13pm it will grab a file created at 11:52am because 11 is bigger than 1. How can I get powershell to care about AM vs PM when looking at LastWriteTime?

Comment: Powershell works with objects and attributes by default not with text. So it does not matter that 11 is bigger than 1 because the `Sort-Object` cmdlet sorts by the DateTime type the `LastWriteTime` attribute represends.

Comment: The sorting works just fine (as @Olaf already mentioned). 11:52AM is earlier than 1:13PM (think of the international time format (ISO 8601) `2021-01-15 11:52:00` vs `2021-01-15 13:13:00`. If you really care about numerical sorting with AM/PM format, you should use `| sort @{e={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')}} -Descending`.

Comment: I ended up using dir *.txt /O-D to get the items in the correct order and then split the resulting text and iterate through the resulting array looking for the first text match for part of the expected file name